# Windows 10 notification buttons don't wrap

Tags: windows-10, notification-area

I'm setting up a new Windows 10 laptop, and I've found (strangely) that my notification area buttons are stacking vertically instead of wrapping to two rows. I dock my taskbar to the right hand side of my screen, and this is what my notification area looks like:

[image: Notification area]

Some Googling about this problem suggested that this is related to the display properties for making stuff "bigger" -- so I went to the Display section of the control panel and sure enough the "make everything bigger" setting was set to 175%:

[image: Control Panel - Display settings]

Switching it to smaller sizes, however, doesn't seem to make a difference. This is a ridiculously high resolution display, and when I set the value down to 100%, the notification icons are still stacked vertically but they're also about a fraction of a centimeter wide.

How do I get the notification area icons to wrap into two columns/two rows? For comparison, this is what my old laptop (also Windows 10 Enterprise) has, which is what I' m trying to get working here:

[image: Notification area, wrapped]

Laptop specs:

- ThinkPad P1 Gen 3 ([this one, I think](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-p/ThinkPad-P1-Gen-3/p/20TJS1RX00))
- Windows 10 Enterprise 20H2
- Display resolution: 3840x2160 (Recommended)